# Prestashop variables - category page

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

Hello is there a variable which is created when we apply search filters. Something like $searchFilters. I need those to update products links, but I can't find it anywhere. Or is there any way to rewrite this url with applied filters?
[url rewrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKjck.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing to the Prestashop Filter, This is handled by the module `ps_facetedsearch`.

The assigning of the URL variables happens in the ps_facetedsearch.php file

This module uses `$this->getPathUri()`, make sure your custom theme does not override the ps_facetedsearch module. if it does you need to make changes in the override module in order to get the result that you want.